# How to get a product modification log in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Is there a way to know what specific changes were made to a product in Prestashop 1.7?

In Advanced parameters> Logs I can see the employee who has made the modification, the severity, the message of the modification, the id of the object that has been modified and the date on which the modification was made, but it does not show me what the modification was. specific change that was made, if the name, price, description etc.

Is there a way to know that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but it's a complex issue, you can hook into dynamic hooks like:

`actionObjecProductUpdateBefore`

and

`actionObjectProductUpdateAfter`

and compare two set of object data to see what has been changed.

Of course if you want to log more detailed informations like changes in Specific Prices etc. you also need to get informations about them before and after product change, it might be a time and resource consuming operation so be careful with it.